# Why is a region polygonally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Why is a region polygonally connected ?

A region is a set, which is open and connected. Let's call the region $S$, I've seen the proof, where you take an element $z_0$ in $S$ and separate $S$ into $2$ disjoint sets, $O_1$, which are polygonally connected by $z_0$ in $S$  and $O_2$, which are not. Both sets are open, and so one concludes that $O_2$ must be empty, but why is $O_1$ not empty ?

Comment: because $z_0 \in O_1$

Comment: @cjackal then the set in the following example would be also polygonally connected or not: the set of points $z=x+iy$ with $y=x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $z_0\in O_1$, so it is non-empty.

Comment: but then a parabola with no thickness would be also polygonally connected ? because you can take any point $z_0$ on it and $z_0$ is always polyg. connected with $z_0$.

Comment: @implicitlee Yes, but it is not open. The theorem only says that an open, connected set is polygonally connected, not any other implication.